# Async operations in WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, web-services

How can I improve this code, without to return async Task?

```
[WebMethod]
public string Login(string login, string password, string deviceId, string appVersion, string xuid)
{            
    var authTask = _SSOFrontendService.GetSSOTokenAsync(login, password, deviceId, appVersion);
    var tokenTimestampTask = _SSOFrontendService.GetSSOTokenTimestampAsync();

    Task.WhenAll(authTask, tokenTimestampTask);
    var authResult = authTask.Result;

    if (authResult.Status == ResultStatus.OK)
    {
        var token = new MappedToken(xuid, login, password, deviceId, appVersion, authResult.Content, tokenTimestampTask.Result.Content);
        var mapTokenTask = _mapTokenService.MapAsync(token);

        Task.WhenAll(_mapTokenService.MapAsync(token));
        return _serializer.Serizalize(mapTokenTask.Result);
    }
    return _serializer.Serizalize(authResult);
}
```

Comment: It's good form to give a little back ground about what your code does. Welcome to CodeReview! =)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I improve this code, without to return async Task?

Doing this doesn't make much sense. If the whole method is going to be synchronous, then you're not gaining much by using asynchronous methods in it, because the synchronous method still needs to block a thread.

Though there might be [a way to make `async`-`await` work with ASMX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623705/41071).

---

```
Task.WhenAll(authTask, tokenTimestampTask);
```

This doesn't do anything at all. `WhenAll()` returns a `Task` that represents the two `Task`s combined, so that you can `await` them. But you're not doing anything with that `Task`.

You could instead use `WaitAll()`, but I don't see any reason for that, using `Result` makes sure that the `Task` is already completed before returning the value (it does this by blocking the thread if the `Task` is not completed yet, just like `Wait()` and `WaitAll()`).

---

```
Task.WhenAll(_mapTokenService.MapAsync(token));
```

I can see three things wrong with this line:

1. The `WhenAll()` issue mentioned above.
2. You have only a single `Task`, so you don't need `WhenAll()` or `WaitAll()`.
3. You're calling `MapAsync()` for the second time unnecessarily.

---

```
if (authResult.Status == ResultStatus.OK)
{
   …
}
return _serializer.Serizalize(authResult);
```

It's often best to deal with the failure state immediately by inverting the `if`:

```
if (authResult.Status != ResultStatus.OK)
{
    return _serializer.Serizalize(authResult);
}

…
```

This way reduces the level of nesting for the main part of the code and also improves its flow (you're dealing with the failure in a single place).

Answer (score 0):

First major thing while using TPL, use exception handling. Its very important to catch the AggregateException and handle the threads behaviour.

Comment: Why is there a specific reason ? And how would you handle the exception?